# Help computing some derivatives of $\frac{\|x-z\||^2}{\|x-z\|^2 + \|y-z\|^2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Ok, this shouldn't be that hard, but I'm having difficulties with this.

Consider a fixed $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the function of two variables $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$f(x,y) = \frac{\|x-z\||^2}{\|x-z\|^2 + \|y-z\|^2}$. I want to compute $\nabla_xf(x,y)$, $\nabla^2_{xx}f(x,y)$ and $\nabla^2_{xy}f(x,y)$.

For $\nabla_xf(x,y)$, putting $D=\|x-z\|^2 + \|y-z\|^2$, I found
$\nabla_xf(x,y) = \frac{2}{D^2}\left[ D(x-z) - \|x-z\|^2(x-z)\right] = \frac{2}{D^2}\|y-z\|^2(x-z)$. Here I simply let the denominator squared and used the $f'g-fg'$ rule on the denominator, then the terms simplified since there is a term $\|x-z\|^2$ being added and subtracted. Now I just differentiate this simplified expression wrt both to $x$ and $y$ to get the other ones:

For $\nabla_{xx}f(x,y)$, putting $N=\|y-z\|^2(x-z)$ I got
$\nabla_{xx}f(x,y) = \frac{2}{D^4}\left[2D^2\|y-z\|^2I - 2DN(x-z)^T\right]$, just using the same derivative rule for the quotient. (Here $I$ is the identity matrix $n \times n$)

And wrt $y$ I got
$\nabla_{xy}f(x,y) = \frac{2}{D^4}\left[2D^2(x-z)(y-z)^T - 2DN(y-z)^T\right]$.

However I'm trying to use it all on a certain program that depends on these guys and it all points that I got the derivatives wrong, and I can't see the mistake for the life of me. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do the $x$ case and leave you the $y$ case
$$
\phi(\mathbf{x})=
\frac
{\lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}
{\lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2 + 
 \lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}=
\frac
{N}{D} 
$$

Note that
$ dD
= dN
= 2(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z})^T d \mathbf{x}$.

Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\phi
&=& \frac{DdN-NdD}{D^2} 
= 2\frac{D-N}{D^2} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z})^T d \mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
The gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= \frac{2\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^2} 
(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z})
$$

Taking the differential once again
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\mathbf{g}
&=&
\frac{2\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^2} 
d\mathbf{x}
-
\frac{4\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^3} 
(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z}) dD \\
&=&
\frac{2\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^2} 
d\mathbf{x}
-
\frac{8\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^3} 
(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z}) (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z})^T d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray*}

The second derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\frac{2\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{z} \rVert^2}{D^3} 
\left[
D \mathbf{I}
- 4
(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z}) (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z})^T
\right]
$$

Comment: I see. Looks like I forgot that there is an additional 2 in the last terms of the 2nd order derivatives. One is from the derivative of the denominator D and other is because of the chain rule, because it's squared. Ty.